# Firebase Test Lab Instrumentation Test Fails At Google Signin

Tags: android, firebase, android-espresso, android-testing, firebase-test-lab

I implemented an app that connects to Google Calendar API to read calendar event of a user. i've been trying to test my application using the Firebase Android Instrumentation Test feature. The features that doesn't require a Login such as home screen were tested and passed just fine. I have not implemented a login yet, but only followed this guide ==> https://developers.google.com/calendar/quickstart/android to make request to google calendar API. When my test reaches this point, a google signin page appears and stays there till the test stops.

A second time, i tried running a Robo test, the test passed fine beyond that phase because i noticed Robo created an Email address to authenticate to google in other to reveal the Activity i am testing for. But i wanted seeing the test result based on the test i wrote.

A third time, i tried running instrumentation test but it failed again. I checked the video and discovered that it stopped this time having a screen with two radio boxes to choose an account. One was an account i suppose created by Robo, and the other was to add a new account.

Please help me on how to specify a default account for my instrumentation test to make use of and get pass the google signin page.

Comment: I would suggest contacting Firebase support for help with this.  https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/troubleshooting/

Comment: Thanks much for your response @DougStevenson. May I ask pls, is it possible to run Firebase Instrumentation Test and make it bypass Login Screens?